# Pass values ​from a subform to a textbox in another access form

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, invoice, subform

I would like to create an invoice in a form, pressing a button from another form with the data. Pressing the button would pass the customer data, dates etc. into different textboxes. But the detail of the purchase, the units, the number of invoices, etc. are in a subform. There is no problem to pass the first item to a textbox in the invoice form. But the issue is that there are several items.

This is my code in the button

```
Private Sub Boton_Click()

Dim strFrmName As String
strFrmName = "FACTURAR"

    DoCmd.OpenForm strFrmName
        With Forms(strFrmName)
             .RUT_2 = Me.RUT
             .REGIS_RECP_2 = Me.registroRecepcion
             .NAME_2 = primerNombre & " " & primerApellido & " " & segundoApellido
             .BOLETA_2 = Me.BOLETA_INV
             .CANT_2 = Me.CANT_INV
           
            'The problems in the subform and thier data...

        End With
End Sub
```

I have tried to pass subform1 to subform2 but nothing works, I have created a vlookup to search on the subform's source table using outside sharing references (placed in the mainform) but it didn't work. Any idea? It's possible?

Comment: What do you mean 'create an invoice' - do you need to create a record or just display existing data on form? There are several ways to pass data from one form to another, even multiple forms as source.

Comment: here is the link to how to refer to a subform from its form and etc.  Unfortunately, this seems to always be painful:  http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm

Comment: I just need to display the existing data on "invoice form" from the register form which has a subform with the detail.The problems is putting the data from the subform in texboxes, a subform or something. It the data that corresponds to each client in particular display in the form with the subform (register). I've seen this website with this table but can't figure it out: access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm. To pass the data, would I have to use something like this? Me!Subform1.SourceObject = Me!Subform1.Form!Subform2.SourceObject. Thank you all for your help, I am new to Access and vba.

Comment: If it's existing data then why don't you build query joining tables and bind form (or better, a report) to query and apply filter criteria?

Comment: You may be right but the database was already made (I didn't make it) and I thought of passing the data from vba as a shortcut. In addition, this data later has to be transformed into a TXT for the electronic billing system. its an idea